# How to creat a menu with icons?

Tags: android, menu-items

I really need some guide or suggestion about how to creat a menu with icons.

I am write an Android app, and I want to creat a menu like this, when I enter this app, I can see the "Main" menu in the center, I can edit the text of the menu.I press the icon of main menu, a "+" icon slide out, then I can add a sub menu with press the "+". And next time, I enter this app, I can see the main menu icon around with some sub menu icons. And if I want, I can press main menu icon to hide the sub menu icon.(I cannot post a image, so I hope you can understand)

Really need help about this.

[image]

Comment: Can you formulate the question better? And maybe provide images via free image hosting such as http://postimage.org/

Comment: Ok, I post an image now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code to make menu in android.And also download these icons from [Android™ Drawables](http://androiddrawables.com/menu.html)

> res/layout/menu.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
      android:title="Save" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="Search" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
      android:title="Share" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
      android:title="Delete" />  

<item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
      android:title="Preferences" />
```

> AndroidMenusActivity.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidmenus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_preferences:
            Toast.makeText(AndroidMenusActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }    

}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot to accept your answer XEENA.In fact, it is not the answer I want, but thank you all the same!!